# I am getting an error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select SID from APPLY
where CName ='STANFORD' OR'CORNELL' OR 'MIT';
```

Comment: You want the `IN` operator. If you use `OR` then you need to repeat the column name for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IN` operator:

```sql
SELECT sid
FROM   apply
WHERE  cname IN ('STANFORD', 'CORNELL', 'MIT');
```

or, use multiple comparisons:

```sql
SELECT sid
FROM   apply
WHERE  cname = 'STANFORD'
OR     cname = 'CORNELL'
OR     cname = 'MIT';
```